# How can I call AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity to access Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

Scenario:
I create an app on Amazon, and use [Login with Amazon](http://login.amazon.com/), which returns an "access_token". Then I run:

```js
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.WebIdentityCredentials({

          RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::416942672???:role/???_amazon_role',
          ProviderId: 'www.amazon.com',
          WebIdentityToken:"?????????"
        });

  AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

  dynamodb =  new  AWS.DynamoDB()   dynamodb.listTables({}, function a(error,data){

    alert( "error: " +  JSON.stringify(error) );
    alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    });
```

When I later run the `ListTable` function it will return:

```
error: {"message":"Missing credentials in config","code":"SigningError","name":"SigningError","statusCode":403,"retryable":false}
```

I found  it  seems that I have  to  call `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`. But how  can I  call it  in [AWS SDK for JavaScript](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/)? Or is there any other process I missed?

Comment: This got me up and running, it's absent from the prev answer: http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/

Comment: And for node.js but it's the same API: http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

The process of [Getting Temporary Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingWIF.html#CreatingWIF-getting-temp-creds) indeed requires a call to [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) - this low level API call is implied in the higher level [AWS SDK for JavaScript](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/) credentials provider call `new AWS.WebIdentityCredentials()` though, see e.g. [Class: AWS.WebIdentityCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WebIdentityCredentials.html):

> Represents credentials retrieved from STS Web Identity Federation
>   support.
>
> By default this provider gets credentials using the
>   [AWS.STS.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRoleWithWebIdentity-property) service operation. This operation
>   requires a RoleArn containing the ARN of the IAM trust policy for the
>   application for which credentials will be given. In addition, the
>   WebIdentityToken must be set to the token provided by the identity
>   provider. See [constructor()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WebIdentityCredentials.html#constructor-property) for an example on creating a credentials
>   object with proper RoleArn and WebIdentityToken values.

Given the error message *"Missing credentials in config"*, you are obviously passing an incorrect `WebIdentityToken`, which isn't a surprise given you just specified some `?????????` placeholders ;) - since you already *use Login with Amazon, which returns an access_token*, you'll just need to pass the content of that ACCESS_TOKEN instead of those `?????????` placeholders as value for `WebIdentityToken` and should be all set.

- For other readers: Section *6. Putting it all together* of [Configuring Web Identity Federation in the Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring-wif.html) provides an example for retrieving the access token via [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). As noted there, *Other identity providers will have a similar setup step that involves loading the respective SDK, logging in, and receiving an access token* - in particular, how to handle [Login with Amazon](http://login.amazon.com/) is documented in detail within [Getting Started for Web](http://login.amazon.com/website).

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS instance in this way:

```
  var aws = AWS ;
  var region = aws.config.region = 'us-east-1';
  var cred = new aws.Credentials(<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>, 
            <YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>, sessionToken = null);
```

To get ACCESS KEY ID and SECRET ACCESS_KEY go to:

AWS IAM>Users>Security Credentials>Access Keys

Now use **aws** instance for further operations.

Comment: Do not use static IAM keys :(